# Can Someone bring a packed phone from US to India

Tags: air-travel, customs-and-immigration, india

One of my friend is coming to India from US. He bought himself a laptop and a camera which he is using their. Also I requested him to get a Nexus 5 phone for me. Is it possible to bring this phone with sealed box in India without any trouble?

Answer (score 0):

Indian customs may want some rupees for a clearly new product. They may want more rupees if your friend doesn't declare it. Other than that no problem.

Also make sure it's unlocked - you don't want an expensive phone that only works on AT&T.